# git: obtain the benefits of `git rebase --interactive` for cherry picks

Tags: git

I'd like to be able to do this:

```
git cherry-pick --interactive hash-0..hash-n-1  # fantasy command
```

and obtain the same workflow as interactive rebase: an editor buffer comes up, containing:

```
pick hash-0
pick hash-1
pick hash-2
...
pick hash-n-1
```

where I can delete any unwanted commits, `squash` them together, or `edit` to pause between the picks to do some manual fixup (like `commit --amend`) and all that.

Note how the `pick` of interactive rebase is tanalizingly like `cherry-pick`.

Now the above operation can be done by performing the cherry-pick first, and then the interactive rebase, which is inconvenient. That is:

```
$ git tag old-head  # mark starting point for later rebase
$ git cherry-pick hash-0..hash-n-1    # get everything first
$ git rebase --interactive old-head   # okay now rebase "in-branch" to fix it up
```

It's not only inconvenient because of the two steps but because it may require resolving conflicts in commits you don't even want that will be discarded in the rebase stage.

Comment: Isn't `git rebase --onto` exactly that?

Comment: @CarlNorum I have no idea; if that is so, can it be expanded into an answer?

Comment: Are you actually trying to cherry-pick the commit range `hash-0..hash-n-1`, or are you looking for an answer that generalizes to arbitrary commits that aren't necessarily ancestors/descendants of each other?

Comment: @Cupcake How about, let's just stick to ancestors. Though really, an arbitary list of commits as well as ranges would be nice, of course.

Answer (score 31):

Okay, figured out a nice trick.

Start a trivial `rebase --interactive HEAD^` over one commit in your current branch.  You get something like:

```
pick 1efd396b * Fixed a bug in frob function
```

Now, just paste in additional hashes that you want to pick:

```
pick 1efd396b * Fixed a bug in frob function
pick f01934db * Awesome feature added
pick 6fd109c1 * Refactored the widgets layer
squash 3900fd77 * Refactored the widgets layer s'more
```

Save and exit, and wee: the `rebase` mule obligingly takes the additional cruft you loaded on its back and incorporates it into the current branch according to the commands.

You can actually do an empty rebase with:

```
git rebase --interactive HEAD
```

you get a buffer containing

```
noop
```

You don't have to delete that; just add your picks after that.

*Addendum:* To produce the pick lists for this method, use `git log --oneline --reverse from..to`, then trim the output needed and prepend the rebase commands to each line: `pick`, `squash`, ...

Comment: If anyone is willing to look through the source, `git rebase` is currently just a Bash shell script that may or may not use cherry-picking under the hood, though that may change in the future if it ever gets ported over into a faster C implementation.

Comment: @Cupcake does that mean that every time you do a `git pull` (that is configured for `--rebase` semantics, or with that option explicitly), it is running shell code?

Comment: Um, `git pull` itself is really just a [shell script](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v2.0.0/git-pull.sh), currently.

Comment: You can let git prepend `pick` like: `git log --format='pick %h %s' --reverse`

Comment: @snipsnipsnip: I see a lot duplicate commit messages, but with different hashes if I run that command... Is it logging the commits from all branches by any chance?

Comment: @CoDEmanX: You need to specify commit range you'd like to pick. ex. `git log --format='pick %h %s' --reverse master^^^^..master^`

Answer (score 4):

Okay, following up on Carl Norum's suggestion, I looked into the `--onto` argument of `git rebase`.

The use case can be satisfied like this, which is an improvement, though still involves a somewhat excessive number of steps.

The primary issue is that rebase needs a current branch to pick from so we have to shift our coordinates to a temporary branch, and then manipulate our original branch head afterward and delete the temporary branch.

The flow looks like this:

```
# We are originally on "mybranch"
# We create a temp-branch pointing to the last commit to be picked: hash-n-1

$ git checkout -b temp-branch hash-n-1   # create branch at last hash

# Then we rebase from the point before the first hash, onto our original branch

$ git rebase --interactive hash-0^ --onto mybranch

# The above rebase should make "temp-branch" into the very object that
# we want "mybranch" to be. If it looks that way, then all that is left is
# make it so:

$ git checkout mybranch          
$ git reset --hard temp-branch
$ git branch -D temp-branch
```

The `git rebase --interactive hash-0^ --onto mybranch` uses the commit before `hash-0` as the "upstream" for the rebase, taking all the commits from the current branch (based on `hash-n-1`) which are not in the upstream. Those commits are, of course, `hash-0` through `hash-n-1`.  They are rebased onto the `mybranch` head, but it is the current `temp-branch` which is `reset --hard` to track the result. So we just have to assign that pointer to `mybranch` and delete `temp-branch`.

It's fairly clumsy, but eliminates the duplicate cherry-picking, and is easy to recover from at any time just with `git reset --hard mybranch`.

(Can this still be improved.)

Comment: As far as I know, this is as good as you're going to get with Git's native porcelain commands. You could possibly construct a simple, easy to use alias that uses plumbing commands to achieve what you originally wanted, but I'm not familiar enough with those plumbing commands to say for sure.

Comment: @Cupcake what happens if we start an interactive rebase, but then add commits (`pick` lines) to it which were not originally there? Will it take them or barf? I have to try it.

Comment: Actually, now that you've mentioned it, I've heard that `rebase` really just runs `cherry-pick` under the hood, but I don't know if that's actually true. I think `rebase` is just supposed to be a shell script, let me check...

Comment: all the commands in `rebase -i` are pretty trivial to do with some combination of `git cherry-pick -e` and `git cherry-pick -n`

Comment: Right, here's [`git-rebase.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v2.0.0/git-rebase.sh) and [`git-rebase--interactive.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v2.0.0/git-rebase--interactive.sh).

Comment: @Cupcake It works; I did a `git rebase --interactive HEAD^` to get started, and then, wee, just added some commits to the list with `pick`. And it took them.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a better answer is out there, but this might work for you

```sh
git cherry | awk '$0=$2' > cherry.txt
"$EDITOR" cherry.txt
git cherry-pick --stdin < cherry.txt
```

[Example](http://github.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg/issues/9#issuecomment-37755385)

Comment: Hmm, not really, but thanks for the `$0=$2` awk trick: slicker than `{ print $2 }`.